# How do I deploy Riak on dotCloud?

Tags: service, riak, dotcloud

How do I get a riak service started on dotcloud? I tried:

```
data:
   riak
```

It says the service is unrecognized.

Answer (score 3):

Riak support on dotCloud is in alpha. You can test it by following the instructions given in [this recipe](https://github.com/jpetazzo/riak-on-dotcloud-ALPHA).